# HTML5 PHPMailer Not Submitting Data

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I was able to get this fixed it was an issue with my JS and I had to change my PHP code. Now the only thing I need to figure out is how to take my PHP code and make it work with smtp (like i had it before)

```
<?php

 $errorMSG = "";

 // NAME
 if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
 $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
 } else {
 $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
 }
 if (empty($_POST["last_name"])) {
 $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
 } else {
 $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
 }

 // ADDRESS
  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
  $errorMSG = "Address is required ";
  } else {
   $address = $_POST["address"];
  }
  // PHONE
  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
   $errorMSG = "phone is required ";
   } else {
   $phone = $_POST["phone"];
   }

   // EMAIL
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
    } else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    // RESTAURANT
    if (empty($_POST["restaurant"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Restaurant is required ";
    } else {
     $restaurant = $_POST["restaurant"];
    }

     // NUMBER OF ORDERS
       if (empty($_POST["num_orders"])) {
        $errorMSG = "Number of orders is required ";
        } else {
        $num_orders = $_POST["num_orders"];
        }

        // ORDER(s)
        if (empty($_POST["order1"])) {
        $errorMSG = "At Least One Order is required ";
        } else {
         $order1 = $_POST["order1"];
        }

        $EmailTo = "bigchinexpress@gmail.com";
        $Subject = "New Message Received";

        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "First Name: ";
        $Body .= $first_name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Last Name: ";
        $Body .= $last_name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Address: ";
        $Body .= $address;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Phone: ";
        $Body .= $phone;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Email: ";
        $Body .= $email;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Restaurant: ";
        $Body .= $restaurant;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Number of orders: ";
        $Body .= $num_orders;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Order 1: ";
        $Body .= $order1;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Order 2: ";
        $Body .= $order2;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Order 3: ";
        $Body .= $order3;
        $Body .= "\n";

        // send email
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

       // redirect to success page
       if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
        echo "success";
       }else{
         if($errorMSG == ""){
             echo "Something went wrong :(";
         } else {
          echo $errorMSG;
         }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: are you using any javascript validator?

Comment: method="post" is added on the <form> as well its just not in the example above ^ (typo)

Comment: If you're adding code, edit your question and add it there. Don't put it in a comment where it can be very difficult to read.

Comment: i updated the post. it didn't go in a code block for some reason however

Comment: Stick a `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP script to confirm what it's receiving.